# In next.js, how to implement session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, next.js, koa

I have some experience of python flask and django, now I'm learning next.js development, and struggling to figure out how to implement session.

My project is using `koa` as the web server and next.js as one middleware, code like this

```js
import next from "next";
import Koa from "koa";
import Session from "koa-session";
import Router from "koa-router";

...
const next_app = next({...});
const handle = next_app.getRequestHandler();

next_app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  server.use(Session(server));  // use koa-session middleware
  ...
  router.get("(.*)", async (ctx) => {
    console.log("server.js session: ", ctx.session);
    ...
    // create or update session data
    ctx.session.custom_data += 123;
    
    // but how to pass ctx.session to handle(), then to page components?
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
});
```

In the above code, `ctx.session` carries the session data for each request, but the problem is I don't know how to pass the session data to next.js, because the next.js entry function call `handle(ctx.req, ctx.res)` doesn't take extra session data as arguments.

Then I look at `next-auth`, which also provide session functionalities, and I'm really deeply confused, which one to use and why?